# Testing Out of View objects in Angular

Tags: angularjs, grid

When you view the DOM behind an angular grid, only those columns which are in view are visible.  When you scroll horizontally, you can see the divs for each column pop in and out of the DOM as they scroll into or out of view.

Is there a way to access wherever Angular is storing ALL the columns?  Since the DOM doesn't contain the out of view columns, as far as Selenium is concerned, the columns don't exist.  Obviously, we could scroll the grid and validate that way, but we're hoping to get an all up view of what columns the user has selected to be visible (even if they aren't currently the scrolled view).

Comment: Can you give an example, preferably in jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co?  Are you using ng-grid from angular-ui and if so can you add those tags?

Comment: Yes, we're using ng-grid from angular-ui.  The grid contains 12 columns.  In IE Dev Tools, for any given row, I can see 10 cells, like so, <div class="ngCell col0 colt0">...</div> to <div class="ngCell col0 colt9>...</div>.  When I scroll over, Dev Tools shows <div class="ngCell col2 colt2"> to <div class="ngCell col11 colt11">. @JasonGoemaat

Comment: Do you set those columns yourself in the config?

Comment: They are set inside an angular JS file inside of a controller block. @JasonGoemaat

Comment: So what exactly do you want?  Can't you just use that pre-existing list?

Comment: The JS file defines what columns are available, not what columns are actually visible or in what order they are in.  A customer may hide columns or re-arrange them.  I'd like to be able to, in my test, say something like Assert.IsTrue(ngGrid.ngRow.Columns[7].Text == "Smith") or Assert.IsTrue(ngGrid.ngRow.Columns["LastName"].Text == "Smith"), even if that column is out of scroll. @JasonGoemaat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking for the answer, a co-worker finally figured it out:

angular.element('#ParentObject').scope().gridData

Where ParentObject is the ID of an element containing the grid you want access to.

This returns all the columns/rows for the grid, even if they are not currently visible.